# Python, Finding nth root of a number

Tags: python

I have to find m root of n. t denotes number of test cases.For each test cases the line with n and m separated by space.output format: for  every test case, if it is an integer print m root of n or else print -1.

It also has some constraints for each variables which i done correctly.
Like `1<=t<=10^5 1<n<30 1<=m<=10^9`. I don't know whats the error.

```
t= int (input())
if (t>=1) and (t<=100000) :
    while (t>0) :
        no=input()
        e=no.split()
        n=int (e[0])
        m=int (e[1])
        if(n>1) and (n<30) and (m>=1) and (m<=1000000000):
            k=m**(1/n)
            if (k==int(k)) :
                print (int(k))
            else :
                print(-1)
        else :
            print(-1)
        t=t-1
else:
    print(-1)
```

Comment: removed version specific tags, removed please

Comment: Is this from an ongoing contest? because if it is, this should be VTCed.

Comment: Also, i just [checked it](http://ideone.com/0PHoEN), there is no error as such. Any test cases please, please check whether `n` and `m` are taken from input in correct order.

Comment: no its just practice problem in hackerearth. i found the error

Comment: thanks guys. i got it corrrect. if(k==int(k)) this line fails for some test cases of k with decimal values. so i round the k value with ceil function and power it up to n then match with actual number m. l=int (math.ceil(k*100)/100)
            r=l**n
            if (r==m) :
                print (l)@ABcDexter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

```
import math
t= int (input())
if (t>=1) and (t<=100000) :
    while (t>0) :
        no=input()
        e=no.split()
        n=int (e[0])
        m=int (e[1])
        if(n>1) and (n<30) and (m>=1) and (m<=1000000000):
            k=m**(1/n)
            #print(math.ceil(k*100)/100)
            l=int (math.ceil(k*100)/100)
            #print(l**n)
            r=l**n
            if (r==m) :
                print (l)
            else :
                print(-1)
        else :
            print(-1)
        t=t-1
```